# How is the state of font-rendering in Chrome under Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, css, gdi

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7. For a long long time, it was plagued by broken rendering of anti-aliased fonts. There were some fonts what looked OK, but some looked terrible. You could recognise a website what were made on a Mac and weren't tested on Windows, as there were a lot of fonts what looked perfect on Mac and were absolutely unreadable on Windows under Chrome.

The ironical thing is that one of the worst website was Google's own http://www.google.com/webfonts/ page.

Most of the fonts on Google Webfonts looked so bad, that it was a bad joke to go there. Even on other font websites, there were only a very few fonts what looked good on Chrome. So few that actually lot of websites started using the same small set of fonts, because of rendering on Windows.

Today, I'm on Chrome 21, and I've just realized that everything looks perfect! Seriously. After a short browsing on the following websites, I've yet to find a font what looked like before:

- http://www.google.com/webfonts/
- http://www.fontsquirrel.com/
- http://www.fontspring.com/
- https://typekit.com/

I've yet to see a font what looks like before. Actually they all look really nice, on par with FF and IE.

What happened? **Did Google finally implement a proper font-rendering in total silence?** I know that the Retina Macbook Pro's font rendering was announced in this version, but the Mac and the Windows font rendering were totally different projects. Is there any chance that the whole font rendering is now unified? (would be quite a surprise without a huge announcement)

I've met an interesting project called [Mactype](https://code.google.com/p/mactype/) on Google's forums, as a workaround for the ugly Chrome rendering, is there any chance that Google actually implemented something similar to Mactype?

Is there any way to see how a website looked in older versions of Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

To test the look of a website under several versions of Chrome, you can try the [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) service. It’s slow but free. Adobe had [a similar free service](https://browserlab.adobe.com), but it’s now paid and much more limited than Browsershots.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are at v24 and its still broken, and dev's at google have pretty much said.. "we're working on it, heres a ton of workarounds if you are a developer".